# Не работает отправка письма пользователям

Tags: php, opencart, ocstore

Использую шаблон FellMart в ocStore 3.0.2.0 и через модуль быстрый заказ хочу отправить клиентам на их почтовый адрес письмо с успешным заказом.

В настройках протокол стоит mail() письмо администратору приходит. Думаю, что это функции в модуле вообще нет. Что в таком случае делать?

Comment: Посмотреть что возвращает функция -_-

Comment: YaMus Это метод отправки а не функция в целом. В админ панели можно выбрать метод  SMTP или Mail()